# what is the scalaz filterM method?

Tags: scala, scalaz

this [scalaz tutorial](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Some+useful+monadic+functions.html) provides an example of using the `filterM` method, but it does not explain it.

```
List(1, 2, 3) filterM { x => List(true, false) }
res19: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(1), List(2, 3), List(2), List(3), List())
```

I see that I can pass it a boolean list of any size. what is this filterM method?

also, is there a book/tutorial of scalaz with a bit more explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty old question. I'll just answer just in case anyone else was wondering.

You can find a pretty good explanation from [Learn You a Haskell for Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more). Search for filterM in the link I referenced.

In the book, it says the following (you can kind of make out the haskell syntax):

> The filter function is pretty much the bread of Haskell programming (map being the butter). It takes a predicate and a list to filter out and then returns a new list where only the elements that satisfy the predicate are kept. Its type is this:
>
> filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
>
> The predicate takes an element of the list and returns a Bool value. Now, what if the Bool value that it returned was actually a monadic value? Whoa! That is, what if it came with a context? Could that work? For instance, what if every True or a False value that the predicate produced also had an accompanying monoid value, like ["Accepted the number 5"] or ["3 is too small"]? That sounds like it could work. If that were the case, we'd expect the resulting list to also come with a log of all the log values that were produced along the way. So if the Bool that the predicate returned came with a context, we'd expect the final resulting list to have some context attached as well, otherwise the context that each Bool came with would be lost.
>
> filterM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
>
> The predicate returns a monadic value whose result is a Bool, but because it's a monadic value, its context can be anything from a possible failure to non-determinism and more! To ensure that the context is reflected in the final result, the result is also a monadic value.

As for a good book for reference, I would read the following Scalaz for a brief tutorial: [Learning Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz). If you need further in depth explanation, I would go back to the learn you a haskell book.

Still doesn't make sense for me what filterM does in the Scalaz example. From the explanation in the Haskell book it makes complete sense.

Edit: clarified what didn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to implementation, you need to pass the function `A => F[Boolean]`, such as `F: Applicative`. 
`filterM` goes over list, filters elements, for which predicate passed ( returned `F[true]` ), and in the end put this `List` into `F`.

A bit simpler example:

```
List(1, 2, 3).filterM[Option](_.some.map(_ % 2 == 0)) // Some(List(2))
```

Note, that this gives you additional degree of freedom, to not only consider `true` or `false`, but as well `None`. You may try it for different Applicatives to grasp the concept.

In the example you put in, the `List` is the Applicative as well. So that, what happens (because it is recursive, it easier to go from the end):
1) when you are at the end of the list - you just get an empty list 
2) you have a list `3 :: Nil`. Applying a predicate to `3` gives you `List(true, false)`. So, you are taking the whole `List(3)` and the tail `List()`.
3) next comes `2`. `2 -> true :: false` which maps to `head` :: `head :: tail` which is `List(2) :: List(2, 3)`. Appending it to what you had before, you are getting `List(List(2, 3), List(2), List(3), List())`
4) now comes the last step, where you get one. The same way you prepend `1` to each of the list for the `true` and take the rest for the `false`.

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(1), List(2, 3), List(2), List(3), List())
```

I added some logging, to make clear what happens:

```
current list: List(1, 2, 3)
current list: List(2, 3)
current list: List(3)
current list: List()
filtered value: List(List())
taking head and tail :   List(3)
taking tail: List()
filtered value: List(List(3), List())
taking head and tail :   List(2, 3)
taking head and tail :   List(2)
taking tail: List(3)
taking tail: List()
filtered value: List(List(2, 3), List(2), List(3), List())
taking head and tail :   List(1, 2, 3)
taking head and tail :   List(1, 2)
taking head and tail :   List(1, 3)
taking head and tail :   List(1)
taking tail: List(2, 3)
taking tail: List(2)
taking tail: List(3)
taking tail: List()
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(1, 2), List(1, 3), List(1), List(2, 3), List(2), List(3), List())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure whats going on but the result is just a truth table. It seems like `filterM` just combines two `applicatives`, one of which is an `applicative of Boolean` so basically the result is an applicative for every combination that results in `true`.

```
1,2,3   (true, true ,true)
1,2     (true, true, false)
2,3     (false, true, true)
1,3     (true, false, true)
1       (true, false, false)
2       (false, true, false)
3       (false, false, true)
()      (false, false, false)
```